# How to turn on auto-complete of brackets in ipython qtconsole

Tags: javascript, python, configuration, qtconsole

In my jupyter notebook the brackets auto-complete which I like.

If I go to the terminal and run `jupyter qtconsole` then my console opens. It is this version:

> Jupyter QtConsole 4.2.1 Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (32-bit)|
>   (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:45)  Type "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.
>
> IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In the qtconsole brackets do not autocomplete - neither do quotation marks. Can I turn them on?

I have the following files:
    `/home/myname/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`
    `/home/jason/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js`

In `custom.js` I have the below - can I add to these files to get the autocomplete behaviour?

```
// leave at least 2 line with only a star on it below, or doc generation fails
/**
 *
 *
 * Placeholder for custom user javascript
 * mainly to be overridden in profile/static/custom/custom.js
 * This will always be an empty file in IPython
 *
 * User could add any javascript in the `profile/static/custom/custom.js` file
 * (and should create it if it does not exist).
 * It will be executed by the ipython notebook at load time.
 *
 * Same thing with `profile/static/custom/custom.css` to inject custom css into the notebook.
 *
 * Example :
 *
 * Create a custom button in toolbar that execute `%qtconsole` in kernel
 * and hence open a qtconsole attached to the same kernel as the current notebook
 *
 *    $([IPython.events]).on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
 *        IPython.toolbar.add_buttons_group([
 *            {
 *                 'label'   : 'run qtconsole',
 *                 'icon'    : 'icon-terminal', // select your icon from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons
 *                 'callback': function () {
 *                     IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('%qtconsole')
 *                 }
 *            }
 *            // add more button here if needed.
 *            ]);
 *    });
 *
 * Example :autoCloseBrackets: true,
 *
 *  Use `jQuery.getScript(url [, success(script, textStatus, jqXHR)] );`
 *  to load custom script into the notebook.
 *
 *    // to load the metadata ui extension example.
 *    $.getScript('/static/notebook/js/celltoolbarpresets/example.js');
 *    // or
 *    // to load the metadata ui extension to control slideshow mode / reveal js for nbconvert
 *    $.getScript('/static/notebook/js/celltoolbarpresets/slideshow.js');
 *
 *
 * @module IPython
 * @namespace IPython
 * @class customjs
 * @static
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this version

*Jupyter QtConsole 4.3.0
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]*

and autocomplete works fine for me on windows.
Try pressing tab it will show you available options, just like linux.